# share point foundation Database

Tags: 2010

1) how many multilple Database can be added to avoid 10GB limit in Windows SBS 2010.?

2) if database of 10 GB is achieved then how to recover from that state?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, most of them not ideal, Take a look at the post below.

http://supportweb.ciaops.net.au/blog/archive/2012/01/20/that-pesky-10gb-limit.aspx